# How can I load a NSAttributeString from a file?

Tags: objective-c, file, object, nsattributedstring, objective-c++

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
self.textInAFile = str;
```

If I wanted a NSString I would have used this code... 
but I want a NSAttributedString, how can I do this? Can you help me?

Comment: Save an attributed string as an RTF file or a Data (NSData) file.

Comment: Does the file contain attributed text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSAttributedString` implements the `NSSecureCoding` protocol, which inherits from the `NSCoding` protocol. So you can save it in a native format:

```
// To save
NSData *data = [NSArchiver archiveDataWithRootObject:attributedString];
[data writeToFile:…];

// load
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:…];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

I want to mention, that there are more sophisticated methods for writing resp. reading data. Go through the documentation of `NSData`. I chose these for simplicity.

However, as mentioned in the comments, you might chose a standard format like RTFD.

Comment: In macOS 10.2 and later, `NSArchiver` and `NSUnarchiver` have been replaced by `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` respectively.

Comment: @Willeke That's correct, but `NSArchiver` never has been deprecated. And in this case, it is meaningless.